# Audio output going to earphone port on starting ubuntu

Tags: 13.10, sound

Whenever I start ubuntu, the audio output by default goes to the earphone port. The speakers work when I insert earphones into the port and then remove them.

I noticed this problem first when I left the earphones plugged in before starting ubuntu.
How do fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Default sinks ares stored in `~/.config/pulse/`. In case audio ports are fine in a guest session (check this first!) we can reset to defaults by removing the pulse configuration directory with:

```
mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.old
```

After that it is advisable to restart the PulseAudio sound server with

```
pulseaudio -k
```